# Match a LiveCycle decimal field to a pattern

Tags: javascript, livecycle-designer

We have a decimal field in a LiveCycle Designer-designed PDF form that is intended to capture a latitude value. I want to make sure that the users enter *exactly* three decimal places.  And I don't want the PDF to create the decimal digits for them.  The user must enter them.

I tried to capture any improperly entered values using a this.rawValue.match(myRegEx) method as shown below in the field's exit event, but JavaScript threw the following error:

```
TypeError: this.rawValue.match is not a function
17:XFA:form1[0]:Page7[0]:Facility_Coord_Latitude[0]:exit
```

Here's the code I was using.  This is confusing because I use this exact approach on a different field.  Although that other field is a text field and this one is a decimal field.  Maybe the "match" method doesn't work for decimal fields?  Any way to convert the decimal value to a string to which I can use the "match" method?  Or any other ideas for how to do this?

```
if (this.rawValue != null){ // only if the field has a value...

    if (
    !this.rawValue.match(myRegex1) && 
    !this.rawValue.match(myRegex2)){ // it doesnt match any of the patterns
    
        xfa.host.messageBox('Please enter your value to exactly three decimal places.');
        xfa.host.setFocus(this.name);
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Sounds like it's not a string. Try `console.log(typeof this.rawValue`)` to debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @CertainPerformance's advice, I figured out the decimal field was indeed not a string.  I tried converting to a string as follows in my validation code:

String(this.rawValue).match(myRegex2)

That worked partially, but it failed if the user entered "000" as the three decimal digits, I think because the decimal field would truncate those trailing zeros before it passed the value to be checked.  So, I think the answer is there's no way unless I convert the field from decimal to text.